# Powershell add-member calculated value

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm writing a script that takes unstructured input, reformats it and spits out a CSV.

In one of the members, I want to do an NSLOOKUP of another member to get the DNS entry associated with the IP. However, a number of the entries have an IP of 0.0.0.0 e.g. it's a listening port, there's no client yet connected.

These throw up errors from NSLOOKUP, quite rightly, because there's no DNS entry for it.

So, I amended my code to only do the NSLOOKUP if the IP was not 0.0.0.0, otherwise return an empty string.

But I can't make it work.

The following throws up no errors:

```
$srcdata -split "`r`n"|foreach {
                    $obj = New-Object System.Object
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Connection_ID  -Value $_.Split(",")[0]
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Filename       -Value $_.Split(",")[1]
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MCP_Port       -Value $_.Split(",")[2]
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_Port    -Value $_.Split(",")[3]
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Port_State     -Value $_.Split(",")[4]
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_IP      -Value $_.Split(",")[5]
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_DNS     -value {If ($obj.Client_IP -ne "0.0.0.0") {(NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP|Select-String Name).Line.ToString().Replace(" ","").Split(":")[1]} else {""}}
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Protocol_Stack -Value $_.Split(",")[6]
                    $outfile += $obj
}
```

But then if I inspect one of the objects in the array I see:

```
Connection_ID  : 1
Filename       : CCF_MARC1
MCP_Port       : 2001
Client_Port    : 0
Port_State     : LISTEN
Client_IP      : 0.0.0.0
Client_DNS     : If ($obj.Client_IP -ne "0.0.0.0") {(NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP|Select-String Name).Line.ToString().Replace(" ","").Split(":")[1]} else {""}
Protocol_Stack : LEGACY
```

If I wrap in parentheses instead of in a scriptblock, so the line setting up the Client_DNS is as follows:

```
            $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Client_DNS     -value (If ($obj.Client_IP -ne "0.0.0.0") {(NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP|Select-String Name).Line.ToString().Replace(" ","").Split(":")[1]} else {""})
```

I get:

```
If : The term 'If' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At K:\CodeSnippets\PowerShell\NW_CONN_TO_CSV.ps1:21 char:91
+ ... NS     -value (If ($obj.Client_IP -ne "0.0.0.0") {(NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP|Selec ...
+                    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (If:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm sure I could get it to work as two separate lines of code, so do the If statement and put the result in a variable, then use that variable as the value in the add-member command, but I'm sure what I'm trying to do is eminently possible, I'm just missing something!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You're interested in a *ScriptProperty* rather than a *NoteProperty*:

```
$obj |Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Client_DNS -Value { 
    nslookup $this.Client_IP |Select-String Name 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Amended that line in my code to `                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name Client_DNS     -value {(NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP|Select-String Name).Line.ToString().Replace(" ","").Split(":")[1]}` and it works perfectly, supressing the error from nslookup where it can't find a DNS entry for an IP, and then still going through my code to pull out only the dns name from the nslookup result. I guess I need to go brush up on the other membertypes as I've only used noteproperty up till now.

Comment: I found I had to change `NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP` to `NSLOOKUP $This.Client_IP` otherwise the Client_IP column in the csv created when I pipe to export-csv was empty and it would take an age.  Also, although that change fixes the output, it seems to take an age - I suspect that it is being calculated as the array is being populated, and then calculated again by export-csv!

Comment: Currently, I've gone with the following - not pretty, but works `                    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
                    $Client_DNS_V = If ($obj.Port_State -ne "LISTEN") {Try { (NSLOOKUP $obj.Client_IP |Select-String Name).Line.ToString().Replace(" ","").Split(":")[1]} Catch {}} else {""};
                    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
                    $obj|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty   -Name Client_DNS     -Value $Client_DNS_V;`

Comment: It is being calculated everytime you dereference the property, ie. when `Export-Csv` enumerates the objects in the array

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to extract the name, something like this:

```
 $outfile = $srcdata -split "[\r\n]" | % {
    $v = $_.Split(",")
    $re = [regex]::match((NSLOOKUP $v[5]), '(?<=Name:\s+)[^\s]+')

    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Client_DNS = @('', $re.value)[$re.success] 
        Connection_ID = $v[0]
        Filename = $v[1]
        MCP_Port = $v[2]
        Client_Port = $v[3]
        Port_State = $v[4]
        Client_IP = $v[5]
        Protocol_Stack = $v[6]
    }
}
```

Comment: That works - problem is I do not understand how! Specifically where $z and $x get populated?